# Zebra datepicker icon not showing in textbox after file download

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ascx page with date text boxes and are assigned the zebra datepicker icons using jquery. In my aspx pages, I use this usercontrol and has 2 buttons - generate button to bind grid view and export button to export to the grid view data to excel and download the excel.

**Problem**:
When clicking on export button, the file downloads and the datepicker icon from the text boxes disappears

**What I have tried**:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", "HideProgress();window.location.href='DownloadFile.ashx';", true);
```

The above code is used to download the file in aspx file. This problem does not occur when clicking on generate button

**NOTE :  This happens only in IE.**

We gave a temporary fix for this by giving the following change.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", "HideProgress();window.open('DownloadFile.ashx';)", true);
```

But the file would sometimes how could not read but sometimes would open correctly.

Comment: I would look at the HideProgress() function to see if it is hiding the wrong things, or perhaps is too broad in what it is hiding and that ends up including the datepicker icon accidentally.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick i have added the function. The function just hides a loading div that contains a loading image and also disables 2 buttons. Does that make any difference?